# FTP quote RCMD CALL from Ubuntu Server to remote UNIX system

Tags: unix, ftp, ubuntu-9.10, quote

I have a file containing my clients articles that weekly needs to be uploaded to a remote UNIX server via FTP and a remote command is used to read the articles into their system (an agency that keeps track of EAN-codes). The people running the remote server gave my client a batch-file to run in order to upload this article file to the server and they've been doing it manually.

The work I do is developing my clients system and I want to automate this file upload. Their system is on an Ubuntu Server, so I've translated the batch-file to a shell-script.

Now, everything works just fine except invoking scripts on the remote server. As soon as the script gets to the command "quote RCMD CALL ..." I get a "500 Command not understood"-error. If I run it frow Windows with the batch-file there is no such error.

I've logged in to their FTP manually and tried to write different quote-commands and none of them work.

I've found people having a similar problem through Googling but couldn't find any solutions.

Does anyone know why this is that the remote command works via Windows but not through Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that our firewall blocked "quote"-commands from being sent through the FTP-client.

Found out about this issue through [AS/400 FTP Question & Answer Sheet](http://www.tylogix.com/Articles/AS400FTPQandA.htm#FTPQUOTE)